# Eclipse Color Theme reverts to default every time I exit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, color-scheme

I am using the native "Dark" theme in Eclipse Luna and then using the Eclipse Color Theme plugin to pick some different editor themes. The issue is that every time I open up Eclipse it is using the defaults that come with the native Dark theme and I have to go and set my Color Theme for the editors every time.

Is there a way I can get it to remember my Color Theme settings?

Comment: Sounds like your configuration area is not writeable.

Comment: It's a known issue more than a year old. And it appears again from time to time (for instance after Eclipse Mars was released). Here the related thread on the _eclipse-color-theme_ project page on GitHub: https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/206

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Preferences -> Oomph -> Preferences recorder -> Enable
then set the theme once again, this time Oomph will record it

Comment: Se-ri-ous-ly? Eclipse never ceases to amaze me in its ability to make simple things imcreadibly hard to achive. -_-

Comment: In Eclipse 2020-12, it was Preferences -> Oomph -> Setup Tasks -> Preference Recorder

Answer (score 3):

This solution work for me: try to change it to Classic and restart your computer. Then change it back to Dark Theme, now the color themes are remembered after restarting Eclipse.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked for me though I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3):

The following works in Eclipse Neon for me:

> @djgeary @jdeyton Try enabling Oomph preferences recorder in Eclipse
>   Mars settings (icon in settings window at bottom part of the screen,
>   near help icon). After that set theme and that it. Next time you
>   launch eclipse Oomph should restore correct theme settings.

Credit goes to [dovydasvenckus](https://github.com/dovydasvenckus) for answer on github, [here](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/206#issuecomment-117970989).

Answer (score 3):

To set up Dark theme as a "global" theme, and the theme you like from Eclipse Color Theme that you installed from Market Place, you can do the following. I used:

1. windows 10 (64 bit, but for 32 bit is probably the same)
2. eclipse oxygen

Steps:

1. Set the "global" theme to the dark theme: (`Windows>Preferences>General>Appearance>Theme:Dark`)
2. close eclipse. (You can change the Color Theme to let's say Recogn Eyes -which is my favorite-)
3. Re-open eclipse. (If you changed the Color theme you will have the default for the Dark theme, since you are reading this)
4. Open File explorer and look for `C:\Users\[user]\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings`
5. Open `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`.
6. Copy text after **`=`**, and **keep that in your clipboard** , in my case it was `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_dark`
7. (In eclipse) Set the schema to default, and close the application.
8. open eclipse and choose your favorite color theme.
9. Close eclipse.
10. Go to the file `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme` again and paste what was in the clipboard (`themeid=org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_dark`, in my case) after the **=**.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got mine to remember syntax coloring. All I had to do was make some changes, click export (export all), then re-import the .epf file. Not sure why this worked for me but hope someone finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (Eclipse Neon). What worked for me:

1. Download the **EPF** file of your theme from http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/
2. Open Eclipse and go to "File" > "Import" > "General" > "Preferences" [Next]
3. Select the EPF file in the "Browse" file-dialog [Open] [Finish]

More info: http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=how-to-use

Answer (score 0):

Nothing from here works for me. I even deleted the workspace and created new one.
The only thing i kept was the git archive containing the eclipse project files and the java stuff.
And still after a restart the first 30s it seems as if it works. Then suddently the colors in the editor changes AND the content of the org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme file changes the theme to "...default:" with some numbers at the end.

I have no plugins installed, only the package downloaded from eclipse.org